# What is the right way to duplicate an OpenCL kernel?

Tags: opencl

It seems that I can duplicate a kernel by get the program object and kernel name from the kernel. And then I can create a new one.

Is this the right way? It doesn't looks so good, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT: To answer properly the question: Yes it is the correct way, there is no other way in CL 2.0 or earlier versions.*

---

The compilation (and therefore, slow step) of the CL code creation is in the "program" creation (clProgramBuild + clProgramLink).

When you create a kernel. You are just creating a object that packs:

- An entry point to a function in the program code
- Parameters for input + output to that function
- Some memory to remember all the above data between calls

**It is an simple task that should be almost for free.**

That is why it is preferred to have multiple kernel with different input parameters. Rather than one single kernel, and changing the parameters every loop.

Comment: But do I have to do the name looking up again and again for the multiple kernels?

Comment: Name lookup should be cheap compared against the compilation. And anyway, the creation only happens at the very beggining of the CL programs. It all depends on how many kernel you generate and how many times. BUt usually that should be the cheapest part of all the chain.

Comment: Guess there is no better solution here. This can do the job but quite fishy. Maybe it's not much of trouble, but can be easily avoid, too. Copying seems to be obviously cheaper than creating a new one from scratch...

Comment: Unfortunately we missed this in the earlier specs. OpenCL 2.1 is adding clCloneKernel to achieve this. Before 2.1 you have to grab a kernel object from the program by name. This should be cheap enough, and you should certainly do it at least per thread (as kernel objects carry state), but there is no way to postpone it to a later copy-constructor style, and no way to copy it including the current argument state.